# Black screen, addSubView:moviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, movieplayer, nsdocumentdirectory

So I have a `UITableView`, and it reads the `NSDocumentDirectory` and displays (in an array) the contents of it in this table.

When you touch a cell, let's say **"21 Jump Street.mp4"** (this is a movie trailer app), it should play the trailer for you entitled **"21 Jump Street.mp4"** in the documents folder.

But when I play the movie, all I get is a black screen. If you tap on the screen you can see that the status bar appears, then disappears, over and over as you tap it. Here's my code in "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`":

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSString *movieLocal = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieLocal isDirectory:NO];
NSLog(@"%@", fileURL);
moviePlayer3 =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
moviePlayer3.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer3.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer3.view];
[moviePlayer3 setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

When I **NSLog fileURL**, this is what it shows:

```
21%20Jump%20Street.mp4 -- file://localhost/
```

Any help would be so awesome. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Is moviePlayer3 an instance variable or a local variable?

Comment: Sorry it's an instance variable from my .h. An mpmovieplayercontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check with a different file to see if maybe the file is corrupt or in an unsupported format encoded?

Comment: Wasn't that unfortunately but I'll give you the answer because it might help someone else, and no one else answered.

Comment: But you did find out what it was?